# DotnetCore Linux Container inside Kubernetes unable to Query External Partner API Endpoint

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, curl, .net-core

Environment: Azure Kubernetes Cluster

Container: Dotnetcore 2.2 Linux

The dot-net core application was able to query the external partner API endpoint but suddenly it started throwing the below is the mentioned exception

ExceptionId: c6c603bb-91cc-4556-98bf-d747903f522a. Error Message:  The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.. Error Details:  System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Also tried the curl command from inside busybox pod and getting this error

Curl command : curl --location --request GET 'external url' --header 'Authorization: token'

Error:
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.

Note:
Other partner API calls are working fine, except this particular partner but the curl from the local system is working. From Pod, it is throwing an error.

What can be the issue:

1. External partner SSL expired. Which the partner is saying that it has not
2. External partner SSL is cached and now invalid in Kubernetes
3. Kubernetes configuration is the problem. What can be the correct one

Comment: Which docker image you are using? It's possible that the CA certificate bundle contain expired certificates.

Comment: As @Allen pointed maybe you need to update the container image or if self-built update base image or update CA certificates in the image. could be but not so common, check if the k8s nodes CA bundle is updated, it sounds as if it could have originated from there also